# Optimising coefficient finding functions

Tags: function-construction

I'm seeking a generalisation to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73549/improve-timings-for-calculating-coeficients/73594?noredirect=1#comment203271_73594), where I am looking to list the coefficients (without repetition) to monomials of the form

$$(x_{1}^{3}+x_{2}^{3}+x_{3}^{3}+x_{4}^{3})^4\cdot(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}+x_{4}^{2})\cdot(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4})^{2}$$

for example.

**Motivation:**

I am currently using the following functions:

```
ip[n_] := Times @@@ Flatten[Table[{Table[Prime@ k, {k, 
Length[IntegerPartitions[n][[s]]]}]}^{IntegerPartitions[n][[s]]}, 
{s, Length[IntegerPartitions[n]]}], 1]

alpha1[omega_] :=  Join[{a^omega},   Times @@ # & /@ Rest@(List @@ # & /@ 
(If[# == 1, 1, If[PrimePowerQ[#] == True, Power @@ {a, FactorInteger[#][[1, 2]]}, 
(Power @@@Transpose@{Take[ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]], 
Length@FactorInteger@#], (Reverse@Sort@FactorInteger[#][[All, 2]])})]] & /@ip@omega))]

timesABC[omega_] := Module[{
aa = Flatten[#] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates[#] & /@ Part[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ 
(Reverse@Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ IntegerPartitions@omega)))),
bb = Table[Length[#] & /@ ((Split[#] & /@ (Reverse@Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ 
IntegerPartitions@omega)))[[nn]]), {nn,Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}],
cc = Table[Plus @@ (Take[ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]], omega]^nn), {nn,omega}]},
Times @@ # & /@ Table[(cc[[#]] & /@ aa[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@aa)[[nn, #]]^
bb[[nn, #]] & /@ Range@Length@bb[[nn]], {nn, Length@bb}]]
```

There are no problems with these functions - they all work fine. The problem is with this:

```
partialON[omega_] := Flatten[#] & /@ ((Part[#, 1] & /@ Part[#] & /@ 
Module[{ff = Expand[#] & /@ timesABC[omega]},
Table[Transpose@{Table[DeleteCases[Coefficient[List @@ ff[[m]], 
alpha1[omega][[n]]], 0], {n, Length@alpha1@omega}], alpha1[omega]},
{m, Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}]]) /. {} -> {0})

partialON@4

(*out

{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 6, 12, 24}}  

*)
```

What this function does is probably best illustrated in table form:

[image]

where the top row are the product inputs, and the rows are the coefficients of the right column.

The function `partialON` works as desired, but is not optimised, hence the question. I can apply [rasher's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73594/9923) to the top column of the table, but only for two groups of parentheses at present. I would ideally like to be able to go as high as `partialON@20`. Currently, `12` is stretching things on my little machine.

## Added

Just for clarity, the full code for generating above type tables:

```
aZ[omega_] := Module[{aa = Table["(" <> ToString[Superscript[Subscript[x, 1],
If[n == 1, "", n]] // TraditionalForm] <> "+.. " <> ToString[Superscript[Subscript[
x, omega], If[n == 1, "", n]] // TraditionalForm] <> ")", {n, 40}],
bb = Table[Plus @@ (Take[ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]], omega]^n), 
{n, omega}],
cc = Reverse@(Flatten[#] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates[#] & /@ Part[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@  
(Reverse@Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] &  IntegerPartitions@omega))))),
dd = Reverse@Table[Length[#] & /@ ((Split[#] & /@ (Reverse@Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] 
& /@ IntegerPartitions@omega)))[[n]]), {n,Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}]}, 
Column@# & /@ Table[aa[[Part[#] & /@ cc[[n]]]]^(Part[#] & /@ dd[[n]]), 
{n, Length@dd}]]
alphax[n_] := ToString[If[n == 1, 1, If[PrimePowerQ[n] == True,Power @@ 
{Subscript[x, 1], FactorInteger[n][[1, 2]]}, Times @@ (Power @@@ Transpose@{Table[
ToExpression["Subscript[x, " <> ToString[i] <> "]"], {i, Length@FactorInteger@n}], 
(Reverse@ Sort@FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]] )})]] // TraditionalForm]
oG3[omega_] := Text@Grid[Join[{Join[Rotate[#, 0] & /@ (Reverse@Flatten@(aZ[omega])), 
{""}]}, Transpose@ Join[partialON[omega] /. 0 -> "", {alphax[#] & /@ ip@omega}]],
Frame -> All, Background -> {None, {{White,  Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Gray}}}, 
Alignment -> {Left, Center},   ItemSize -> {Join[
Table[7, {x, Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}], {Automatic}]}]

oG3@5
```

Comment: Nice question, +1. I recall this work deals with some partition experimentation, perhaps add info. on what these structures are (e.g., "I'm looking at counting how many ways foo in sets of bar can be partitioned into baz sets...") might lead to more compact solutions.

Comment: OK, a quick stab at this netted 30-100X faster than *CoefficientRules* on 5 variables, "internal" powers between 2 and 5, "external" powers between 2 and 5. I'm verifying correctness (using a different method, I don't think the mathematical trickery used earlier applies here). Rather than decode the code and the paper involved (interesting article, BTW), can you specify some useful to you upper bounds on number of vars, maximum "internal" and "external" powers, and if the powers are disjoint, or disjoint for internal/external, or.... this will help with deciding on which routes to pursue.

Comment: Also, might be worthwhile to query on *Math.StackExchange* - see if someone there is expert in the area and might have a short-cut method for this kind of coefficient gathering. I've also got a sneaking suspicion the group theoretical functions in *Mathematica* might have a use here.

Comment: @rasher that sounds great - 30-100X sounds good to me :) re MSE, I have asked previously, but will try to word better. Meanwhile I will look up groupfunctions on MMA. I don't know re variables - I have just gone with that safe (and time consuming) option where `var=ipow+pow` using your definitions from the last question.

Comment: See the non-answer answer for now, need to hit the hay, will ponder the core problem and the rest of your code this week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not (at this time) a direct answer to the core question, perhaps better thought of as a placeholder. Nonetheless, it will serve as an example of how to speed up this problem, and like things in general.

You need to start thinking in "*Mathematica*" terms. That is, whenever possible, think of how you might manipulate things *en masse*, as operations on vectors, matrices, lists, etc. If you can vectorize things in *Mathematica*, it;s nearly always a win.

By way of example, I started to decode your code in the OP to get a better understanding of what you're after. Here's the first function, *Mathematica*-ized:

```
newip[n_] := Times @@@ (Prime@Range[Length /@ #]^#) &[IntegerPartitions[n]];
```

How much of a difference does that make?

[image]

We have to view it in Log scale to even see the faster way:

[image]

By the time *N* is 30, this is over 250X faster.

I'll update this as I go through your code, and if the current ideas for the core problem flesh out, I'll add them.

Update 24/02/2015:

OK, here's the coefficient finder I've been tooling with.

Some caveats: It's obviously a work-in-progress, parts within that could be combined are separated to allow profiling of them individually, some parts certainly could be further optimized (e.g. using *outer* vs mapping over sets for low cardinality partition sets), etc., but perhaps there's some useful stuff here for you.

I've not tested it on huge arguments compared to native *Mathematica* methods - I do my play puzzling on leisure netbook & laptop, so no testing on real workstations was done...

This takes arguments similar to the earlier answer in the linked question, e.g.

```
(x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6])^10 (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + 
   x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 + x[6]^2)^10 (x[1]^3 + x[2]^3 + x[3]^3 + 
   x[4]^3 + x[5]^3 + x[6]^3)^2
```

is represented with the first two arguments being the "internal" and "external" powers:

```
{1, 2, 3, 2, 2} , {10, 1, 2, 4, 5}
```

the third argument is the exponent set you're after, e.g.:

```
{17, 9, 7, 1, 1, 1}
```

representing an exponent set in six variables. You can use things like

```
{17, 9, 10} or  {17, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0}
```

for terms with zero exponents, they are treated equivalently.

A quick test on the above case gives this an ~2500X speed advantage over your *coeff*, and about a 10X advantage over *Coefficient* in *Mathematica*. I'd expect the gap to grow as problem size grows. It is also *much* gentler on memory resources.

As stated in my comment, getting *all* is still faster using something like *CoefficientArray* (I've yet to find the Kryptonite for this problem, any luck for you over at *Math.StackExchange*?), but I'm guessing that's a no-go for you due to memory or other resource pressure?

```
getCoeff[ipow_, epow_, expset_] :=
 Module[{f, fastRF, myIP, px = {{}}, target = DeleteCases[expset, 0], 
   set = Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {ipow, epow}], nres, x, bin,
    tset, breaks, accs, splits, seqs, res},

  (* fugly patch for now *)
  If[(Tr[ipow*epow] < Tr@target) || (Min@target < Min@ipow), Return[0]];

  fastRF[a_List, b_List] := Module[{c, o, x}, c = Join[b, a];
    o = Ordering[c];
    x = 1 - 2 UnitStep[-1 - Length[b] + o];
    x = FoldList[Max[#, 0] + #2 &, x];
    x[[o]] = x;
    Pick[c, x, -1]];

  myIP[set_, used_, left_, n_] := 
   With[{tmp = fastRF[set, used]}, 
        (* Another fugly patch for non-conformance *)
         If[Length@tmp < left, Return[{{}}]];
         IntegerPartitions[n, Length@tmp - left, DeleteDuplicates@tmp]];

  tset = Tally[set];

  Module[{cnt = #[[2]], tmp, reset = #[[2]]}, 
     bin[#[[1]], x_] := (tmp = Binomial[cnt, x]; cnt -= x; 
       If[cnt == 0, cnt = reset]; tmp)] & /@ tset;

  (f[#[[1]], z_] = z <= #[[2]]) & /@ Tally[set];

  nres = Module[{z = 0}, 
    Nest[With[{zz = #}, z++; 
       Join @@ (Module[{mip = myIP[set, #, Length@target - z, target[[z]]], tmp = #},
                       mip = Join[tmp, #] & /@ mip;

            Pick[mip, Apply[And, Apply[f, Tally /@ mip, {2}], {1}]]] & /@ 
                             zz)] &, px, Length@target]];

  breaks = Accumulate@target;
  accs = Accumulate /@ nres;

  Reap[Do[
     x = Join @@ Position[accs[[z]], Alternatives @@ breaks];
     x = Differences[Prepend[x, 0]];
     splits = 
      Transpose@{Span @@@ Transpose[{Accumulate[Prepend[Most@x, 0]] + 1, Accumulate[x]}]};
     segs = Tally /@ Rest@Extract[nres[[z]], Prepend[splits, {{}}]];
     res = Times @@ Join @@ Apply[bin, segs, {2}];
     Sow[res];, {z, Length@nres}]] // 
   If[#[[2]] == {}, 0, Tr@#[[2, 1]]] &

  ]
```

A quick run-through:

Sub-function *myIP* is a restricted partition generator. It takes size and member restrictions and is used to build the candidates for each of the target exponent set components. It uses Mr. Wizard's *fastRF* to cull the restrictions. I may have a faster method, but it's an inconsequential part of the process, and his code is so pretty, so I kept it.

I the build a set of custom binomial coefficient functions *bin[...]*. These return the coefficient given the target value but *keep track internally* of how many of that value are available, resetting to the initial tally when exhausted for each candidate partition set.

Following, I build a set of *f[...]* functions that allow quick validation of the tallies of candidate partition sets (i.e., does the set have a valid amount of each possible piece).

The next step fills *nres* with valid partition sets using the above.

Finally, I parse the candidate partition sets, splitting them at the points where the running "stuttering" totals equal the target coefficients, tally these, extract the results using an [undocumented form of extract](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46261/undocumented-form-for-extract) I discovered for speed, and applying the adaptive *bin* binomial coefficient extractors. Lastly, I check if the result is empty (coefficient set was invalid) and return 0 (invalid) or the total of the coefficients (valid).

I hope at least some piece of this finds use, and will continue pondering this interesting puzzle (I'm convinced there's a better way, mathematically justified, that perhaps someone with deep multinomial/poly-product knowledge can answer with over at your *Math SE* query).

Update 25/02/2015 per comments:

Looking at your test harness, there's an obvious issue - you can't just *Quiet* something and expect that errors sans messages means the same performance. Even though using *Quiet* does usually reduce timings when errors cause messages, there's still overhead in *Mathematica* handling the issue, and of course the likelihood that there's a cascade of problems presented to the code... also on large result lists, using rules can be quite inefficient for replacements. Look into *Dispatch* and using *Replace* directly with a limited level specification if you have tasks that need to do such things in the future.

Since the original question, comments, *Math.SE* question, etc. all implied the feeding of well-conditioned exponent lists, this was built with that in mind. I've added another ugly patch for now, but be advised, it just short-ciruits the problem, but it also means there's work, sometimes a lot, getting done where it need not be.

That said, I took your code, and just changed one line to be:

```
getCoeff[Sequence @@ Transpose@Tally@list1, #] & /@ list2
```

in your *partialONk* function. No other changes made, so there's extra work converting the argument format, and the extra work being done in my function because bad sets are passed to it. Nonetheless, the following is the result (netbook timings, I ran out of patience at 12):

[image]

Both grow quickly (expected from the problem), but the original *coeff* *explodes*.

There appears to be *much* overhead from the rest of your code, based on just timing the coefficient functions. I'd venture re-thinking it, and in particular generating only valid exponent sets, will go a long way in improving timing. As it stands, much of the boost in finding the coefficients is getting swamped in other overhead. By example, the two functions, over a range of 1 to 5 components, each with random powers between 2 and 5 for internal/external power, and a random exponent set of appropriate size. I gave up at six components - *getCoeff* finished in under a second, I aborted *coeff* after twenty minutes. At five components, *getCoeff* was ~2800 times faster... N.B. This had to be done with a *Log scale* so *getCoeff* would even show up on the plot:

[image]

Comment: yes, much cleaner (and faster!) :) I'll continue to look through the group theory stuff too, though not turned anything up yet that's too useful ...

Comment: @martin Spent some more time on this, frankly drawing blanks at this point - method I thought might be useful turns out not to be, so back to drawing board. Highly recommend pursuing the core question (fast coefficient determination given an exponent set since the latter can be generated easily). I'd venture there's someone there that might have the specific background to provide info or advise there's no real short-cut. I'll continue pondering...

Comment: ok - will follow up on MSE - will let you know if I get any joy over there. I have been looking at it & there certainly seems to be some sort of pattern, but it is eluding me for now too.

Comment: posted a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155816/fast-way-to-generate-list-of-distinct-coefficients), hope I haven't missed anything.

Comment: @martin See chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21280/chat-with-rasher-and-martin), an idea that so far seems solid, not sure how practical, might lead to some revelation perhaps...

Comment: Incredible! It took me a while, but I think I get it now! Now ... how to apply it!!??

Comment: have posted comment to chat. BTW, do you know how to turn on notifications for chat so they appear in main SE?

Comment: I got a solution based on your observations in chat, but is very far from optimised!!

Comment: I was wondering if you had a reference for the binomial transformation? I would like to do a bit of reading on the subject. Also, I think a possible complete solution could be to used the hook length formula, but need to do a little further reading on that too! :)

Comment: @martin: Reference? Rasher, I suppose ;-) . That's just my creation, and I'm *quite* sure it's nothing new - it follows from deconstructing how coefficients get formed. I've got a finder that is much much faster than using MMA for individual sets, but CoefficientArray beats it to get all - but I'll post the WIP when time permits, it might have some interesting tidbits for you.

Comment: that's great - looking forward to learning some new stuff :)

Comment: @martin: Added the item I've been goofing with, still pondering the truncated product method mentioned in our chat. Let me know what you think...

Comment: @martin ? Do you mean something's missing in that code?

Comment: my mistake, it works great! loads faster ! - Will continue to play with it & let you know how I go :)

Comment: -I'm nearly there with it - but is throwing up `3 bin$247952[{{}}, {Transpose[1 + Most[0, {}] ;; {}]}]` for impossible entries. How do I skip these / replace them for 0?

Comment: @martin: Hmm, when I ran bad exponents through it, it gives 0 - can you give me an example case (in the format of the arguments, inner, outer, exp. list)? I'll give it a poke. Off to eat, back later...

Comment: `getCoeff[{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {4, 1, 1, 1, 1}]`

Comment: @martin - OK, quick patch (I assumed only *possible* valid. exp. sets would be in args, but not completely invalid, since I assumed generation of valid exp. sets elsewhere. In any case, take peek at top of code (updating now), will make better fix on return (as in *Return* is uncool construct, IMO).

Comment: still not fixed for me I'm afraid. I botched a quick patch with `getCoefficient[omega_] := 
 With[{listO = 
    Quiet[Table[
      Table[With[{aZz = Reverse@aZ2[omega]}, 
        getCoeff[(aZz[[mm]])[[1]], (aZz[[mm]])[[2]], \
(IntegerPartitions@omega)[[nn]]]], {nn, mm}], {mm, 
       Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}]]}, 
  Replace[listO, x_ /; Not@NumericQ@x :> 0, {2}]]` which has timing of 70 sec for `getCoefficient[11]` as opposed to 21 secs for `partialONk[11]` as described below. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @martin: See update. Also, let's continue further discussion in our already set-up chat - this is getting cluttered.

Comment: thanks for all of your help on this - eventually squeezed 18 out of it :)

Answer (score 3):

Have managed to get sn improvement in the method given in the OP using rasher's reveltation in [this chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21280/chat-with-rasher-and-martin) & Mr.Wizard's [`removeFrom`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18105/9923)

```
subs[num_, list_] := 
DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ Select[Subsets[list], Total@# == num &]]

removeFrom[b_List, a_List] := Module[{f}, f[_] = 0;
(f[#] = -#2) & @@@ Tally[a];
 Pick[b, UnitStep[f[#]++ & /@ b], 1]]

coeff[list1_, list2_] := With[{cc = subs[#, list1] & /@ list2},
With[{df = 
 DeleteCases[
  If[removeFrom[Sort@list1, Sort@Flatten@#] == {}, #, 
     0] & /@ (Tuples[cc]), 0]}, 
 Total[Times @@ # & /@ 
 Table[With[{ff = 
     Join[{Flatten[Split[#] & /@ df[[nn]], 1], 
       Join[{list1}, 
        Most@(removeFrom[list1, #] & /@ 
           Table[Flatten[
             Take[Flatten[Split[#] & /@ df[[nn]], 1], n]], {n, 
             Length@Flatten[Split[#] & /@ df[[nn]], 1]}])]}]},
   Table[
    Binomial[Count[ff[[2, m]], First@ff[[1, m]]], 
     Length[ff[[1, m]]]], {m, 
     Length@Flatten[Split[#] & /@ df[[nn]], 1]}]], {nn, 
   Length@df}]]]]

 aZ2[omega_] :=
 Module[{aa = Table[n, {n, 100}],
 bb = Table[
 Plus @@ (Take[ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]], omega]^
    n), {n, omega}],
 cc = Reverse@(Flatten[#] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates[#] & /@ 
       Part[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ (Reverse@
           Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ 
           IntegerPartitions@omega))))),
 dd = Reverse@
 Table[Length[#] & /@ ((Split[#] & /@ (Reverse@
           Flatten[#] & /@ (Split[#] & /@ 
           IntegerPartitions@omega)))[[n]]), {n, 
   Length@IntegerPartitions@omega}]}, 
Table[{aa[[Part[#] & /@ cc[[n]]]], (Part[#] & /@ dd[[n]])}, {n, 
Length@dd}]]

partialONk[omega_] := 
With[{list2 = 
Table[Flatten[
  Join[Table[#[[1]], {xx, #[[2]]}]] & /@ 
   Transpose@(Reverse@aZ2[omega])[[yy]]], {yy, 
  Length@aZ2[omega]}]},
Table[With[{list1 = list2[[zz]]},
coeff[list1, #] & /@ list2], {zz, Length@list2}]]

partialONk[4]
```

which can calculate `partialONk[16]` without too much trouble (though timing is not great). The code could certainly benefit from some optimizing though!